# Parent scope update child scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I found many ways to update parent scope variable from child scope, which is The Dot, but in my case that didn't help.

I have ui-bootstrap accordion which open and collapse according to isOpen variable which I pass it from the backend.

```js
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function AccordionDemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.items = [{
    label: 'Item 1',
    open: true
  }, {
    label: 'Item 2',
    open: true
  }, {
    label: 'Item 3',
    open: true
  }];

  $scope.opened = false;
}
```

```html
<accordion id="accordion_main">
  <accordion-group ng-repeat="item in items" heading="{{item.label}}" is-open="item.open">
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
<span class="btn btn-default" id="toggle_all" ng-click="m.open=!m.open">Collapse All</span>
```

I want to make a collapse all button, which is outside of the scope of ng-repeat. If there is a better way to make a collapse all button please advice,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ngClick to loop through your items and set them to false.

```
<span class="btn btn-default" id="toggle_all" ng-click="collapseAll()">Collapse All</span>
```

JS:

```
$scope.collapseAll = function(){
    for(var x = 0; x < $scope.items.length; x++){
        $scope.items[x].open = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: this solution worked but it caused the accordion to stop responding after opening and closing the accordions for multiple of times.

Comment: This function only collapses, please provide the code for the toggle part you're referring too.

Comment: I tried to make a mock like the case i'm facing: http://plnkr.co/edit/09hBLusmXqXnmwJpuVH5

Answer (score 0):

you can use another var in scope like:

```
$scope.collapse_all = false;
```

And in page

```
<accordion id="accordion_main">
  <accordion-group ng-repeat="item in items" heading="{{item.label}}" is-open="!collapse_all && item.open">
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
<span class="btn btn-default" id="toggle_all" ng-click="collapse_all=!collapse_all">Collapse All</span>
```

Comment: I received the following Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression '!closeAll && item.open' used with directive 'accordionGroup' is non-assignable!